# Remove dot(.) from specific columns using gsub and awk

Tags: unix, awk, gsub

I want to remove dot(.) only from the 4th and 5th columns of the table.

```
input
1    10057   .       A       AC      
1    10146   .       AC.      A       
1    10177   .       A       AC      
1    10230   .       AC      .A,AN    
1    10349   .       CCCTA   C,CCCTAA.              
1    10389   .       .AC      A,AN



desired output
1    10057   .       A       AC      
1    10146   .       AC      A       
1    10177   .       A       AC      
1    10230   .       AC      A,AN    
1    10349   .       CCCTA   C,CCCTAA              
1    10389   .       AC      A,AN
```

So I tried the following command.

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} {gsub("\.","",$4);gsub("\.","",$5)}1' input
```

and I got this result (The whole 4th and 5th columns were removed).

```
1    10057   .          
1    10146   .            
1    10177   .        
1    10230   .       
1    10349   .                 
1    10389   .
```

Can you please point out where I have to modify?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you use a string to hold an RE (e.g. `"\."`) the string is parsed twice - once when the script is read by awk and then again when executed by awk. The result is you need to escape RE metacharacters twice (e.g. `"\\."`).

The better solution in every way is not to specify the RE as a string but specify it as an RE constant instead using appropriate delimiters, e.g. `/\./`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} {gsub(/\./,"",$4);gsub(/\./,"",$5)}1' input
```

Comment: is it possible to use: awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} {for (i=4,i<=5,++i);gsub(/\./,"",$i)}1' input

Comment: yes, of course. If there were more than 2 fields to work on then a loop would be the way to go. With just 2 fields it doesn't matter.